# What is the correct preposition---"no objection in/at/to"? Also, advise on other aspects of grammar in the options provided

Tags: grammar

Which of the following options is grammatically correct?

1. The undersigned has no objection in the foreclosure of the work
2. The undersigned has no objection at foreclosing the work
3. The undersigned has no objection in foreclosing the work
4. The undersigned has no objection to foreclose the work

Background: The undersigned wants to convey to the higher authority that he does not have any objection if the work is foreclosed.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the closest to what you are trying to say, but with "to" as the preposition instead of "in."

> the undersigned has no objection to the foreclosure of the work